# Retrieving Email Template using plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I want to retrieve the email title through Guid of the template. Is there any way I can get the titles?

Here is my code. I am also filtering the templates.

```
public static void TemplateLogic(IOrganizationService service, string selected_option)
{
    var queryBuildInTemplates = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "template",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("templateid", "templatetypecode"),
                Criteria = new FilterExpression()
            };

            queryBuildInTemplates.Criteria.AddCondition("templatetypecode",
             ConditionOperator.Equal, "contact");
            EntityCollection templateEntityCollection = service.RetrieveMultiple(queryBuildInTemplates);
}
```

Comment: any followup questions ?

Answer (score 1):

Add "**title**" in the list of attributes to be queried in `ColumnSet` in your above code.

```
ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("templateid", "templatetypecode", "title"),
```

Your code is filtering based on `templatetypecode` for value of "**contact**", thats why it is using `service.RetrieveMultiple` method.

If you know the record id guid, ie `templateid`, then it is a different call.

```
Entity template = service.Retrieve("template", templateId, new ColumnSet(true));
```

`new ColumnSet(true)` will query all the attributes.